# Searching Multidimensional Array for Value PHP

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I feel like this is a pretty easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

```
$array = ('colors' => array('red','orange'),
          'numbers'=> array('one','two')
         );
```

How do a perform a search on the `$array` to determine if `colors` contains a value of `red`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in array function to do this. Thes simplest way to to it in the specific case youve given is to do:

```
$hasRed = (isset($array['colors'] && in_array('red', $array['colors']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be;

```
$hasRed = isset($array['colors']['red']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array_search("red", $array[ "colors" ])
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I've been trying, but it doesn't seem to be working in my application... unless, of course, it doesn't return boolean... my code is `if (!array_search("red", $array["colors"])) {}` but it isn't working

Comment: That will tell him which key red is if it exists.. not give him a definitive boolean answer.

Comment: @Dave: well if it is the first element then it will return `0` which will evaluate to false in your if statement. youlle need to change your statement to `if(false !== array_search('red', $array['colors'])` if you use array search. thats why i recommended `in_array` in my answer.. unless you need to know what the key is for `'red'`.